# Apply a function to all rows except the current one (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm learning the `dplyr` R package and really liking it so far. One thing I need to do is create a new column whose value for each row is the result of applying a function to all rows except the current one (possibly subsetted by group), but I can't figure out a neat way of doing it.

A contrived example would be

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)
x <- mtcars %>% mutate(name=rownames(mtcars)) %>% filter(cyl==4) %>% select(name,cyl,mpg)

# This is what I want to do more elegantly
x$othermpg <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(x))
    x$othermpg[i] <- mean(x$mpg[-i])
```

Here, the `othermpg` column gets the mean of the `mpg` values for all cars except the one in the current row.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and desired output. Generally you would probably want to look into `mutate`

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of `mutate` but don't know how to get this particular behaviour. I'll try to put together an example and amend the question shortly.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @hadley The specific dataset that I'm currently looking at is made up of historical results from Formula 1 racing. It is typical to compare a driver to his team-mate(s), so I want to aggregate information from all other drivers in the same car in a given season into, for example, a column for average points per team-mate. I could imagine other cases where it might be useful to calculate a summary statistic of some sort without each individual row, but don't have other specific examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done in `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(x)[, N:= 1:.N][, othermpg2:=mean(x[N!= .BY, mpg]), by=N][,N:=NULL]
  x
  #             name cyl  mpg othermpg othermpg2
  #1:     Datsun 710   4 22.8    27.05     27.05
  #2:      Merc 240D   4 24.4    26.89     26.89
  #3:       Merc 230   4 22.8    27.05     27.05
  #4:       Fiat 128   4 32.4    26.09     26.09
  #5:    Honda Civic   4 30.4    26.29     26.29
  #6: Toyota Corolla   4 33.9    25.94     25.94
  #7:  Toyota Corona   4 21.5    27.18     27.18
  #8:      Fiat X1-9   4 27.3    26.60     26.60
  #9:  Porsche 914-2   4 26.0    26.73     26.73
 #10:   Lotus Europa   4 30.4    26.29     26.29
 #11:     Volvo 142E   4 21.4    27.19     27.19
```

- The idea was to first create a row index/column `N:=1:.N`
- Group based on that index `by=N]`
- `x[N!= .BY, mpg]` gives the rows of `mpg` that are not equal to the grouping variable
- do the mean
- `N:=NULL` As N is not needed, that column is dropped.

Or you could try (Inspired from @thelatemail's answer)

```
 setDT(x)[, N:=1:.N]
 setkey(x, N)
 x[,othermpg2 := mean(x[!.BY, mpg]), by=N][,N:=NULL]
```

Or without creating `N` (from @Jon Clayden's comments)

```
 setDT(x)[, othermpg2:=mean(x[name!=.BY,mpg]), by=name]
```

Using `dplyr`, this seems to work

```
x %>% 
mutate(N=1:n()) %>% 
do( data.frame(.,othermpg2=sapply(.$N, function(i) mean(.$mpg[!.$N %in% i]))))
  #             name cyl  mpg othermpg  N othermpg2
  #1      Datsun 710   4 22.8    27.05  1     27.05
  #2       Merc 240D   4 24.4    26.89  2     26.89
  #3        Merc 230   4 22.8    27.05  3     27.05
  #4        Fiat 128   4 32.4    26.09  4     26.09
  #5     Honda Civic   4 30.4    26.29  5     26.29
  #6  Toyota Corolla   4 33.9    25.94  6     25.94
  #7   Toyota Corona   4 21.5    27.18  7     27.18
  #8       Fiat X1-9   4 27.3    26.60  8     26.60
  #9   Porsche 914-2   4 26.0    26.73  9     26.73
  #10   Lotus Europa   4 30.4    26.29 10     26.29
  #11     Volvo 142E   4 21.4    27.19 11     27.19
```

Comment: Clever, thanks! This also takes a bit of parsing but at least it's easily generalisable. Learning `data.table` is next on my list...

Comment: Very nice answer! +1. I think this is also doable using keys as shown by thelatemail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25130426/559784).

Comment: I guess the `N` column doesn't really need to be created, since the `name` column is similarly unique for each row. `setDT(x)[, othermpg2:=mean(x[name!=.BY,mpg]), by=name]` seems to work...

Comment: @Jon Clayden; Yes, that seems to work.  If you need a `dplyr` solution, this seems to work `x %>% mutate(N=1:n()) %>% do( data.frame(.,index=sapply(.$N, function(i) mean(.$mpg[!.$N %in% i]))))`

Answer (score 4):

For the sample case, you can use the following code to avoid a for loop. Basically, instead of excluding the "current" row, you simply subtract it from the total:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% mutate(othermpg2 = (sum(mpg)-mpg) / (length(mpg) -1 ))

#             name cyl  mpg othermpg othermpg2
#1      Datsun 710   4 22.8    27.05     27.05
#2       Merc 240D   4 24.4    26.89     26.89
#3        Merc 230   4 22.8    27.05     27.05
#4        Fiat 128   4 32.4    26.09     26.09
#5     Honda Civic   4 30.4    26.29     26.29
#6  Toyota Corolla   4 33.9    25.94     25.94
#7   Toyota Corona   4 21.5    27.18     27.18
#8       Fiat X1-9   4 27.3    26.60     26.60
#9   Porsche 914-2   4 26.0    26.73     26.73
#10   Lotus Europa   4 30.4    26.29     26.29
#11     Volvo 142E   4 21.4    27.19     27.19
```

In case you feel like this can't be applied to your real data, please edit your question with a more representative example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but although this will be faster to run I'm not sure it's a step forwards in readability. It's also likely to be error-prone for more complex functions. In any case, I'm really wondering whether there is a general way of doing this.

Comment: @JonClayden, akrun provided a nice answer and (not sure) perhaps the approach can be transferred to dplyr somehow. But, in terms of code readability and simplicity I personally find my approach very simple and not error prone - it is _very_ basic "maths". As I said, if you're looking to do this with more complex functions, it would be good to have such a more complex function in your question so it can be tested.

Comment: This can be made more readable by defining a function: `leaveoutmean = function(df,n){(sum(df[[n]]) - df[[n]])/(nrow(df)-1)}` and then it becomes `mutate(othermpg=leaveoutmean(x,"mpg"))` and you get a reusable function into the bargain.

Comment: Sure, I agree that for simple functions like `mean` this is a perfectly workable approach, but personally I prefer @akrun's solution for generality.