# How to apply mutate to all rows except current row

Tags: r

I have ratings for `n` restaurants. I want to find the average rating for every `n-1` combination

e.g.

```
store   rating

MCD     4
BK      5
CVS     2
DQ      2
WM      1
AAPL    5
MSFT    5
```

n = 7

The total average is `(4+5+2+2+1+5+5)/7`

without MCD, it is `(5+2+2+1+5+5)/6`

How do I find all of these combinations such that:

```
rating.without  avg.rating

MCD             (5+2+2+1+5+5)/6
BK              (4+2+2+1+5+5)/6
CVS             (4+5+2+1+5+5)/6
DQ              (4+5+2+1+5+5)/6
WM              (4+5+2+2+5+5)/6
AAPL            (4+5+2+2+1+5)/6
MSFT            (4+5+2+2+1+5)/6
```

`tribble` for convenience:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~store, ~rating,
  "MCD",  4,
  "BK",   5,
  "CVS",  2,
  "DQ",   2,
  "WM",   1,
  "AAPL", 5,
  "MSFT", 5
)
```

Comment: No idea about a tidyverse method, but this is pretty doable in data.table - `setkey(dat,store); dat[, .(means = dat[!.BY, mean(rating)]), by=store]` as per previous answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129750/data-table-drop-key-rows-and-summarize/25130426

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do :

```
df$avg.rating <- (sum(df$rating) - df$rating)/(nrow(df) - 1)
df
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  store rating avg.rating
#  <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 MCD        4       3.33
#2 BK         5       3.17
#3 CVS        2       3.67
#4 DQ         2       3.67
#5 WM         1       3.83
#6 AAP        5       3.17
#7 MSFT       5       3.17
```

We can translate the same into `dplyr` by

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(avg.rating = (sum(rating) - rating)/(n() - 1))
```

Comment: Ingenious. Tricky but really simple too.

Comment: @Sas yes, Since you want to ignore the current value from the total `sum`, we do `sum(df$rating) - df$rating` and then and then consider only `nrow -1` rows to take mean.