# How to summarize by_group excluding values of group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Is there a way to exclude the data of a group when summarizing in dplyr?

```
df=data.frame(Group=c("A","A","B","B"),Value=c(1,2,3,4))
Result=df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarise(max = max(Value), exclude(Group))
```

the expected results should be:

```
A 4
B 2
```

4 is the maximum value after excluding all data of group A, and vic for B

Comment: 4 will be the maximum value after excluding data of group A, and 2 will be the maximum after excluding data of group B

Comment: Previous *data.table* solution for this, since it is tagged as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129750/data-table-drop-key-rows-and-summarize/25130426 - suggesting `setkey(df,Group); df[, .(maxval = df[!.BY, max(Value)]), by=Group]`

Answer (score 3):

Another *dplyr* effort, using similar logic to the linked *data.table* answer, which references the overall dataset and current grouping variable within each grouping operation:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(maxval = max(df$Value[df$Group != cur_group()[[1]]]) )
## A tibble: 2 × 2
#  Group maxval
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 A          4
#2 B          2
```

Comment: and because of the [tag:data.table] tag, the `data.table` version of this: `as.data.table(df)[, maxval := max(df$Value[df$Group != Group[1]]), Group][]`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the max by group then iterate taking the max again excluding the current group:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise(max = max(Value),.by = Group) |>
  mutate(max = map_dbl(Group, \(x) max(max[Group != x])))

  Group max
1     A   4
2     B   2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df, Group1 = Group) %>%
  tidyr::crossing(df) %>%
  filter(Group != Group1) %>%
  summarize(max = max(Value), .by = Group1)

  Group1   max
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A          4
2 B          2
```